# What is the configuration for benchmarking Cassandra 4 node cluster

Tags: cassandra

I am running 4 node Cassandra cluster in VMWare ESXi 6.7 and I am using ycsb for testing 4 node Cassandra cluster. The results are not at all as expected i am just getting 20000 ops/sec with 4 node cluster. could some please let me know what is the configuration for benchmarking Cassandra below is my configuration file.

```
cluster_name: 'test-cluster'
num_tokens: 256
hinted_handoff_enabled: true
max_hint_window_in_ms: 10800000 # 3 hours
hinted_handoff_throttle_in_kb: 1024
max_hints_delivery_threads: 2
hints_directory: /mnt/hints
hints_flush_period_in_ms: 10000
max_hints_file_size_in_mb: 128
batchlog_replay_throttle_in_kb: 1024
authenticator: AllowAllAuthenticator
authorizer: AllowAllAuthorizer
role_manager: CassandraRoleManager
roles_validity_in_ms: 2000
permissions_validity_in_ms: 2000
partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
data_file_directories:
    - /mnt/cassandra-data
commitlog_directory: /mnt/commitlog
disk_failure_policy: stop
commit_failure_policy: stop
key_cache_size_in_mb: 0
key_cache_save_period: 14400
row_cache_size_in_mb: 0
row_cache_save_period: 0
counter_cache_size_in_mb:
counter_cache_save_period: 7200
saved_caches_directory: /mnt/saved-cache
commitlog_sync: periodic
commitlog_sync_period_in_ms: 100
commitlog_segment_size_in_mb: 32
seed_provider:
    # Addresses of hosts that are deemed contact points. 
    # Cassandra nodes use this list of hosts to find each other and learn
    # the topology of the ring.  You must change this if you are running
    # multiple nodes!
    - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
      parameters:
          # seeds is actually a comma-delimited list of addresses.
          # Ex: "<ip1>,<ip2>,<ip3>"
          - seeds: "192.168.50.235,192.168.50.254"
concurrent_reads: 64
concurrent_writes: 32
concurrent_counter_writes: 32
concurrent_materialized_view_writes: 32
memtable_allocation_type: heap_buffers
memtable_flush_writers: 4
index_summary_capacity_in_mb:
index_summary_resize_interval_in_minutes: 60
trickle_fsync: true
trickle_fsync_interval_in_kb: 256
storage_port: 7000
ssl_storage_port: 7001
listen_address: 192.168.50.235
start_native_transport: true
native_transport_port: 9042
start_rpc: false
rpc_address: localhost
rpc_port: 9160
rpc_keepalive: true
rpc_server_type: sync
thrift_framed_transport_size_in_mb: 15
incremental_backups: false
snapshot_before_compaction: false
auto_snapshot: true
tombstone_warn_threshold: 1000
tombstone_failure_threshold: 100000
column_index_size_in_kb: 64
batch_size_warn_threshold_in_kb: 5
batch_size_fail_threshold_in_kb: 50
unlogged_batch_across_partitions_warn_threshold: 10
compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec: 0
compaction_large_partition_warning_threshold_mb: 100
sstable_preemptive_open_interval_in_mb: 50
read_request_timeout_in_ms: 5000
range_request_timeout_in_ms: 10000
write_request_timeout_in_ms: 2000
counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms: 5000
cas_contention_timeout_in_ms: 1000
truncate_request_timeout_in_ms: 60000
request_timeout_in_ms: 10000
cross_node_timeout: false
endpoint_snitch: GossipingPropertyFileSnitch
dynamic_snitch_update_interval_in_ms: 100 
dynamic_snitch_reset_interval_in_ms: 600000
dynamic_snitch_badness_threshold: 0.1
request_scheduler: org.apache.cassandra.scheduler.NoScheduler
server_encryption_options:
    internode_encryption: none
    keystore: conf/.keystore
    keystore_password: cassandra
    truststore: conf/.truststore
    truststore_password: cassandra
client_encryption_options:
    enabled: false
    optional: false
    keystore: conf/.keystore
    keystore_password: cassandra

internode_compression: all
inter_dc_tcp_nodelay: false
tracetype_query_ttl: 86400
tracetype_repair_ttl: 604800
gc_warn_threshold_in_ms: 1000
enable_user_defined_functions: false
enable_scripted_user_defined_functions: false
enable_materialized_views: true
windows_timer_interval: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats really 1 node with a single disk having competition across 4 instances of cassandra. Make sure each instance has its own disk (no database can run faster than its disks). If want to run 4 instances of cassandra on a single host do it with ccm or just 4 different instances bound to own interfaces instead of using virtualization to slow it down.

ycsb is pretty bad at benchmarking cassandra, try using cassandra-stress that ships with cassandra. Theres also limits a single client can do where you need to start using multiple clients (separate systems) when pushing over 100k.

Comment: I realized that ycsb is not a good tool for benchmarking Cassandra. I started working on Cassandra stress tool here is the breakdown of my operation. First, the loaded database using write "bin/cassandra-stress write n=4000000000 -rate threads=800 -node node1 -log file = read_1M_UNI_test.log"  i got 35000 ops/sec and then i perform read operation test using "cassandra-stress read n=1000000 no-warmup cl=one -mode native cql3 -schema keyspace="keyspace1" -rate threads=96 -node node1 -log file = read_1M_UNI_test2.log" i am just getting 3000 ops/sec with 100ms latency. I am not sure whats wrong.

Comment: are you using 1 host with 4 vms on it?

Comment: Eventually I wanted to do that if I get good results in 1 node Cassandra VM. Now I am running 1 single node Cassandra VM and 1 VM for Cassandra stress tool. I am putting Cassandra and cassandra stress tool on different VM but on same host.